# exception not caught in windows iot core application

Tags: c#, exception, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I am working on a windows iot core application running on a rasberry pi3
i tried to create/fetch the device key from the azure iot hub using the methods below

```
public MainPage()
    {
        systemName = "RaspIot";
        this.InitializeComponent();

        /* Register for the unloaded event so we can clean up upon exit */
        Unloaded += MainPage_Unloaded;

        registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        AddDeviceAsync().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task AddDeviceAsync()
    {
        Device device;

        try
        {
            device = await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(new Device(systemName));
        }
        catch (DeviceAlreadyExistsException)
        {
            device = await registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(systemName);
        }

        deviceKey = device.Authentication.SymmetricKey.PrimaryKey;
    }
```

If the device with name "RaspIot" is already registered an exception is thrown.
This is working fine in a .net45 console application. but in the UWP application for the PI3 the exception is thrown (pops up in while debugging) but not captured by the catch). what should i do differently?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue. And when running the UWP app using your code, the UI hangs and is not responsive. So it is not a best practice in UWP app.

In the UWP app, you can directly use `AddDeviceAsync()` without `Wait()`. It will execute normal and can catch the exception.

But in the console app, the app will exit without getting the task completion if you remove `Wait()` operator. So they are different.

For calling asynchronous APIs in UWP you can reference [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/call-asynchronous-apis-in-csharp-or-visual-basic).

**Update:**

And it is not recommended register a device in the MainPage function since it will always be executed every time the app is started.